# Meteor - Mongodb: Removing values from second level object

Tags: javascript, mongodb, meteor

I have a document inside a collection that is two array levels deep. I  can not seem to remove them from my Meteor project in the Mongodb database. Basically I want to remove or "unset" the "map_group.users" individually. When I click a button to call the method below, it removes all of them. not the one I want in particular.

**DATABASE**
[image]
**client js**

'click .ig_map_remove_user'(event){
        event.preventDefault()

```
    Meteor.call('remove_instragram_group_map_user', FlowRouter.current().params.group_name, this.username, this.id, this.profile_picture, function(err) {
        if (err) {
            console.log(err)
            console.error('Could not remove user from group.')
        } else {
            console.log('User removed from group')
        }
    })
}
```

**server js**

```
remove_instragram_group_map_user: function(group, username, id, profile_photo){
        instagram_collection.update({
            user_id: Meteor.userId(),
            "map_group.group_name": group
        }, {
            $unset: {
                "map_group.$.users": {
                    "username": username,
                    "id": id,
                    "profile_photo": profile_photo
                }
            }
        })
    }
```

Comment: you need $elemMatch. something like {map_group: {$elemMatch: {username: username}}}

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want to use `$pull` not `$unset` which basically removes the field. Assuming usernames are unique in that array, you can match directly on that:

```
    instagram_collection.update({
      user_id: Meteor.userId(),
      "map_group.group_name": group
    },{
      $pull: {
        "mapGroup.$.users": {
          "username": username
        }
      }
    })
```

Comment: I tried that, but it comes back with an error and the documents in the collection remain.

Comment: It is just the typical 500 internal error with no real description. Just that it failed.

Comment: Can you see my answer and update yours, so I can accept it.

Comment: Forgot the $ sorry!

Answer (score 1):

I get it with the help of Michels answer

```
instagram_collection.update({
            user_id: Meteor.userId(),
            "map_group.group_name": group
        }, {
            $pull: {
                "map_group.$.users": {
                    "username": username
                }
            }
        })
```

Comment: you should upvote/accept  Michel's answer if it helped you.